# Test for a dot in bash

Tags: bash, if-statement

How can I test if some string is dot in bash? I've tried this:

```
if [ "$var" = "." ]
```

and this:

```
if [ "$var" = "\." ]
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: does `echo '${var}'` produce a `.` with no spaces, or extra characters? Run your script as /bin/bash -x ./scriptname, to see what is actually going on.

Comment: Can you post a short, simple example script and the results you get demonstrating that "it doesn't work", because it works fine for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works for me:

```
$ d=.
$ if [ $d = '.' ];then echo 'yes'; else echo 'no'; fi
yes
$ d=foo
$ if [ $d = '.' ];then echo 'yes'; else echo 'no'; fi
no
```

Answer (score 1):

My code:

```
#!/bin/bash

var="."

[ $var = "." ] && echo "Yup, it equals '.'"

exit 0
```

Which prints:

```
Yup, it equals '.'
```

Debugged:

```
tpost@tpost-desktop:~$ /bin/bash -x ./foo.sh
+ var=.
+ '[' . = . ']'
+ echo 'Yup, it equals '\''.'\'''
Yup, it equals '.'
+ exit 0
```

You probably have some white space in `$var` (or perhaps `$var` is empty?), run it through `/bin/sh -x ./yourscript.sh` to see what its actually comparing.

Keep in mind, **==** is a *bashism*, it only works in Bash. Its there as a creature comfort for people who are used to a single **=** resulting in an *assignment*.This is fine if you are only using bash, but you never know what /bin/sh on some systems may point to. Its better to just use **=** and avoid the problem altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Try doubling the equals (`==`), comparing is not the same as assigning.

Comment: In Bourne/bash, the = operator is used for both.

Comment: -eq can only be used for integer comparison. = needs to be used for strings.

Comment: @Ray, I was speaking in general, but you are correct. When comparing integers, =, == and -eq do the same thing in bash.

Comment: This is bad advice on two counts: 1) assignment is nowhere near. 2) The fscking use of `==` instead of `=` for string comparison makes the script immediately unportable.